# How to automatically install required packages from a Python script as necessary?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, fedora

Is there anything in Python or Linux what basically instructs the system to "install whatever is necessary". Basically I find it annoying to install python packages for each new script/system/server that I work on. Each time I end up doing a `sudo pip` or an `apt-get` or `dnf` anyway. Why not automate that within the script itself. Wherever a 'no package found' error crops up, pass the library name to the install statement. Is this there ?

PS: I know docker exists, but am talking at a Python/script level or a direct system level for purely execution purposes.

Answer (score 98):

> How to automatically install required packages from a python script as necessary?

Let's assume that your Python script is `example.py`:

```
import os
import time
import sys
import fnmatch
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
print('test')
```

You can use [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) to automatically generate a `requirements.txt` file based on the `import` statements that the Python script(s) contain. To use `pipreqs`, assuming that you are in the directory where `example.py` is located:

```
pip install pipreqs
pipreqs .
```

It will generate the following `requirements.txt` file:

```
requests==2.23.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
```

which you can install with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 24):

The best way I know is, create a file `requirements.txt` list out all the packages name in it and install it using **pip**

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Example `requirements.txt`:

```
BeautifulSoup==3.2.0
Django==1.3
Fabric==1.2.0
Jinja2==2.5.5
PyYAML==3.09
Pygments==1.4
SQLAlchemy==0.7.1
South==0.7.3
amqplib==0.6.1
anyjson==0.3
...
```

Comment: How about including a `setup.py` file?https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html

Comment: @Unni can you add the details in the answer, I haven't used setup.py

Comment: Is it possible to integrate the code you include in setup.py within your target script anyway, so any complicated script that needs to run with a lot of required libraries, the first block of code (from setup.py) would run and take care of all these issues. @Unni

Answer (score 4):

You can use setuptools to install dependencies automatically when you install your custom project on a new machine. Requirements file works just fine if all you want to do is to install a few `PyPI` packages.

[Here](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/) is a nice comparison between the two. From the same link you can see that if your project has two dependent packages `A` and `B`, all you have to include in your setp.py file is a line

```
install_requires=[
   'A',
   'B'
]
```

Of course, `setuptools` can do much more. You can include setups for external libraries (say C files), non PyPI dependencies, etc. The [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies) gives a detailed overview on installing dependencies. There is also a really good [tutorial](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on getting started with python packaging.

From their example, a typical setup.py file would look like this.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='funniest',
      version='0.1',
      description='The funniest joke in the world',
      url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
      author='Flying Circus',
      author_email='flyingcircus@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['funniest'],
      install_requires=[
          'markdown',
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

In conclusion, it is so simple to get started with `setuptools`. This package can make it fairly easy to migrate your code to a new machine.

Comment: the install_requires only defines the required packages, right? it won't actually install them if the environment doesn't have them. If so, how can we tell the package to install all requirements when they install our package?

Comment: The packages will be installed when you run `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 1):

## Automatic requirements.txt updating approach

I'm not really sure about auto installing what is necessary, but it you stop on using **requirements.txt**, there are 3 approaches:

1. Generate requirements.txt after development, when we want to deploy it. It is performed by `pip freeze > requirements.txt` or `pipreqs` for less messy result.
2. Add every module to requirements.txt manually after each install.
3. Install manager that will handle requirements.txt updates for us.

There are many answers for the 1-st option on stackoverflow, the 2-d option is self-explanatory, so I would like to describe the 3-d approach. There is a library called **to-requirements.txt**. To install it type this:

```sh
pip install to-requirements.txt  # Pip install to requirements.txt
```

If you read the whole command at once you would see, what it does. After installing you should setup it. Run:

```sh
requirements-txt setup
```

It overrides the pip scripts so that each `pip install` or `pip uninstall` updates the requirements.txt file of your project automatically with required versions of packages. The overriding is made safely, so that after uninstalling this package the pip will behave ordinary.

And you could **customize** the way it works. For example, disable it globally and activate it only for the required directories, activate it only for git repositories, or allow / disallow to create requirements.txt file if it does not exist.

**Links:**

1. Documentation - https://requirements-txt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
2. GitHub - https://github.com/VoIlAlex/requirements-txt
3. PyPI - https://pypi.org/project/to-requirements.txt/

Answer (score 0):

## pip3 install pipreqs

## pip3 install -U --user pipreqs

```
mv requirements.txt  requirements.txt.orig
pipreqs --force ./
```

and

> cat requirements.txt

```
Keras==2.2.4 
scipy==1.3.0 
numba==0.44.1 
imgaug==0.2.9 
opencv_python==4.1.0.25
```

BUT, some modules needs binary compilation (where you don't have libraries) and some could be installed by system package manager with different names.