# Forcing pip to install all requirements of my PyPI package

Tags: python, pip, pypi, requirements.txt

I have created an uploaded a package to PyPI. I have generated the `requirements.txt` file within the package too. How can I now ensure that when a user does `pip install MyPackge`, all its dependencies are also installed?

Comment: pip should handle that automatically by reading the requirements.txt, provided it's all been packaged up correctly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419607/how-to-automatically-install-required-packages-from-a-python-script-as-necessary

Comment: Not only requirements.txt; pip will also read setup.py to check and install the dependencies.

Comment: Please read through https://packaging.python.org/ and associated articles linked therein.

Comment: If you followed this [guidelines](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html) pip will install all necessary dependencies.

Comment: Pass a list of package names via `install_requires` kwarg in the `setup` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically install required packages from a python script as necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419607/how-to-automatically-install-required-packages-from-a-python-script-as-necessary)