# pip package Log-Reader is not getting successfully installed via requirements.txt

Tags: caching, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to install pip package 'Log-Reader' through requirements.txt in my vevn. But it uses cache and is not getting installed.

**First I tried**

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Output:**

---

```
Collecting Log-Reader==2.0

  Using cached Log_Reader-2.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.7 kB)
```

---

**Then I tried**

```
 pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

**Output**

---

```
Collecting Log-Reader==2.0

  Downloading Log_Reader-2.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.7 kB)
  (*without the progress bar as below*)

Collecting pycparser==2.20 

  Downloading pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 112 kB 8.0 MB/s
```

---

When I did

```
pip freeze
```

Either way, Log-Reader is not enlisted

When I further into documentation and forums, it says it is better to delete the cache in ~/.cache/pip.

1. Should I uninstall wheel? is it a good solution or
2. Should I delete cache? If yes,
   what is the command to do?

Can someone please help on it? ANy suggestions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419607/how-to-automatically-install-required-packages-from-a-python-script-as-necessary

Comment: I need some serious help...

Comment: Using cached Log_Reader-2.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.7 kB)... Where can I find this file...FYI...I clear .cache/pip/wheels directory..