# Method of opening .py scripts without packages installed? (pip)

Tags: python, pip

Essentially want to send a script to my friend to go over. He has python installed on his computer, but doesn't specifically have 'pyinputplus' - a key component of the program.

Is there a way that I can send this script to him without him installing pyinputplus? Or whether I can effectively insert 'pip install pyinputplus' into the code and have it execute when he runs it? I had also considered making the script an executable, but didn't think that would help.

Relatively new to this, so apologies for my naivety.

Thanks.

Comment: can't he install it? or you can try something import subprocess
````
import sys
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])````

Comment: You may compile it into .exe/.app/whatever on linux using pyinstaller or make command run when script started using subprocess module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/14191957 https://stackoverflow.com/q/12059509/14191957

Comment: Also take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46419607/14191957

Comment: Can’t stop finding links! https://stackoverflow.com/a/36761640/14191957

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I was unsure how to word the question - and typing it a few different ways didn't bring up related questions either. I will check these out !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen)

Comment: That last link is brilliant! Thank you so much for your effort in finding those links

Answer (score 0):

indeed you can give him directly the source code of the librairy.
Using in python the command `sys.path` you can found all folders where python will search for theses librairies.
Just give him the folder and let him place it inside a result of his `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work with someone else on a script is to use a **repository**.
You can create a free one on github for example.

You will put your code there with some git command OR using a GUI to do it (you can download for free **SourceTree**). This tool will allow you to send your code (files) on the repository and to your body to get it back.

Then you can add a requirement.txt file that will include all the dependencies.

To generate it, just run the command :

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This file will contain all the dependencies you need to run the script.

Your body, then can download all the dependencies easily by running :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But actually, you should also use a virtual environnement for each of your project. This will allow you to not mix up all the dependencies of all the project together.

If you want to learn more about it, check this page :
https://blog.usejournal.com/why-and-how-to-make-a-requirements-txt-f329c685181e

Comment: You can also make the requirements.txt file manually and send him with the script. But anyway, he will need to install python. 
Each line is linked to a dependency and the dependency version. 
In your case : 
pyinputplus~=0.2.12

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you. The person in question is more just running the program to see if he encounters any errors - and is not very tech savvy, which is why I'd thought of inserting it on my end within the code