# Way to parse python code for all packages that need installing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a block of code in python that has a variety of import statements and code interleaved. I cannot change the code coming in, but I can parse and reorganize it if it helps.

Silly but repro-able code follows:

```
import numpy

a = 20

import sys

b = 30 

from os import cpu_count

c = cpu_count()

import urllib

ip = urllib.urlopen('http://whatismyip.org').read()

from pandas import DataFrame as _df

df = _df()
```

I would like to parse this code to find 'numpy', and 'pandas' (both libraries that need installing and are not part of the system libraries).

I don't care if something has already been installed (pip can take care of that dependency analysis).

Further complicating it is that I need to do this statically - prior to running the code. I've looked at the importlib (https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec) stuff, but nothing seems like a fit.

Suggestions?

Comment: You can use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module to find the `import` statements but this is not as trivial as it seems. Multiple PyPI packages can provide the same module (for example both `PIL` and `Pillow` can satisfy a `from PIL import Image` line while the former is not maintained anymore). See https://blog.replit.com/upm to see how repl.it does it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically install required packages from a python script as necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419607/how-to-automatically-install-required-packages-from-a-python-script-as-necessary)

Comment: Well, some bad news here. PyPI package names are separate from namespaces they provide. So, for example, there are a few dozen packages providing namespace `numpy`, e.g. `intel-numpy`, a version optimized for Intel CPUs. In some cases, it can be resolved relatively easy (e.g. by picking the oldest/most popular package), but there are many, many cases where the choice is not obvious.

Comment: `pipreq`, suggested by @Kraigolas, maintains a pre-selected mapping of namespaces to package names. It will work in most cases, but there are plausible scenarios when it will pick wrong packages.

Comment: This could be it! Lemme try it out