# How can I configure PyCharm so that it automatically installs any missing Python package?

Tags: python, pycharm

When running a Python script in Python, Python packages are sometimes missing from the python environment being used:

[image]

How can I configure PyCharm so that it automatically installs any missing Python package?

Comment: not sure, why would you need that? Seems like a security issue. A simple requirements.txt should help with that

Comment: @SuperStew what's the security issue? requirements.txt  aren't always provided.

Comment: There have been packages found to have malware etc in them. I certainly wouldn't want my IDE to go installing random packages willy nilly. Even if there isn't a requirements file, just taking a peak at the script should help you catch most missing packages.

Comment: @SuperStew thanks, the script is sent by coworkers and running in a VM. I prefer to automate

Comment: just make a requirements file?

Comment: @TomMcLean I was trying to avoid that step

Comment: your coworker should be able to easily make one like `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to send with the code

Comment: So if anyone mistypes `itertools` as `itertool` you want PyChar to install a possible existing package with that name? Doesn't seem to be the best of ideas to me.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Why? Its easy to create one

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt anyway you can do it yourself like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419607/how-to-automatically-install-required-packages-from-a-python-script-as-necessary

Comment: @TomMcLean  Thanks, I know, I wrote that answer. I was trying to avoid that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said - wise to avoid automatic installs

Run deployments in PyCharm via a CLI rather than the Studio.  This will facilitate construction of batch scripts to drive the install (in your preferred OS interpreter).  The output of installs are then easily spooled to a log file.  Then a couple of commands filtering the log file for (e.g.) "No module named ' "

Weeding out these lines - it is then possible to construct an script to install the missing dependencies

Answer (score 0):

One can click on the package name in the import section, then <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> -> `install package [package name]`:

[image]

Tested in PyCharm 2021.3 (Professional Edition).